# How do you use wine?

Tags: installation, wine

I recently bought a Canon Pixma ip2700 printer. I tried to install it, and the computer wouldn't let me, saying it was not compatible with the current operating system. I think I don't know enough about wine and would like to learn more. I was able to successfully install MIDIsport, but that's it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry so much for installing the canon printer software via wine. Your best bet would be to look up how to install a printer in Ubuntu and leave the software alone. For your wine question, check out a program in the software catalog called "Play On Linux". It is a very simple way to use Wine and will even help you to install prerequisites needed for programs.